# Remove words enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I remove words enclosed in parenthesis in Word 2007

**Example:**

From this: Michael Winkelman (Ben), Steven Benson (Joey),

To This: Michael Winkelman, Steven Benson,

Answer (score 7):

I don't have Word 2007, but in 2003 if you click the 'More' on the Find and Replace dialog, then click 'Use Wildcards', you can enter

\(*\)

into the "Find what" box and leave the "Replace with" box blank.  Clicking Replace All will then remove words enclosed by parentheses.